# Eclipse not showing my src and layout child files

Tags: android, layout

Eclipse is not showing my src and layout child files.

I newly installed android sdk with the help of video tutorial. In that video after adding a new project there are some java files in scr and layout folder. But in my system I cannot get those files. Help me with the problem.

Comment: Can you tell how you got that problem? The question is not explaining the whole problem, so you might not get answer that you may need

Comment: Thnx for your reply
i newly installed android sdk with the help of video tutorial
in that video after add a new project in that scr and layout folder have some java files. but in my system i didnt get that files.

can u help me friend

Comment: Did you go to Android Project? Does the project run on device or emulator?